# Adding icon to Tkinter GUI while compiling

Tags: python, tkinter

I make my GUI calculator and compile it with pyinstaller. All is Ok, I add an icon to it with the help of pyinstaller. But i also want icon to be in the right
top corner. I try to add:

```
root.iconbitmap('calculator.ico')
```

But when I open .exe file after compiling I get an error.
What can i do?

[image]

Comment: Could you also include the error message, and/or a traceback?

Comment: Put the `calculator.ico` in the exe folder.

Comment: @Nouman Thanks, but can i do something to put icon and .exe in one file?

Comment: Hmmm, I think the answer is no. But whats the problem when you have your icon.ico with other files including exe?